# How can I upgrade ruby version on Circle CI 2.0 for Xcode projects?

Tags: ruby, circleci

I sat the config.yml and .ruby-version to upgrade ruby.

But I got an error message `unknown Ruby: ruby-2.6.2`

It used the ruby-2.3, and It has no problems.

How can I set ruby 2.6.2 with config.yml?

**config.yml**

```
defaults: &defaults
    macos:
      xcode: "10.0"
    shell: /bin/bash --login -eo pipefail
aliases:
  - &prepare
    | 
      git submodule update --init --recursive
      gem install bundler
      bundle install
  - &filter-only-master
    branches:
      only:
        - master

version: 2
jobs:
  ios:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:ios
      - run: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      - store_test_results:
          path: build/reports
  macos:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:macos
      - run: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      - store_test_results:
          path: build/reports
  facebook_utils:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:facebook_utils:ios
      - run: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      - store_test_results:
          path: build/reports
  twitter_utils:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:twitter_utils:ios
      - run: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
      - store_test_results:
          path: build/reports
  parseui:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:parseui:all
  deployment:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: |
            xcrun simctl create "Apple TV 1080p" com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-11-0
            bundle exec rake package:release
  jazzy:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: ./Scripts/jazzy.sh
  carthage:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:carthage
  cocoapods:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: *prepare
      - run: bundle exec rake test:cocoapods

workflows:
  version: 2
  pr:
    jobs:
      - ios
      - macos
      - facebook_utils
      - twitter_utils
      - parseui
      - jazzy
  nightly:
    jobs:
      - deployment
      - cocoapods:
          requires:
            - deployment
      - carthage:
          requires:
            - deployment
    triggers:
      - schedule:
          cron: "0 1 * * *"
          filters: *filter-only-master
```

**.ruby-version**

```
ruby-2.6.2
```

I get an error message below

```
#!/bin/bash --login -eo pipefail
git submodule update --init --recursive
gem install bundler
bundle install
^D^Dchruby: unknown Ruby: ruby-2.6.2
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: I don't use the MacOS executor, but as far as I know it is a real MacOS environment. Could you install Brew or MacPorts, and get your preferred Ruby version that way?

Answer (score 4):

In CircleCI 2.0 you need to check which ruby versions are installed for the specific [macOS container image](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/testing-ios/#supported-xcode-versions) that you are building with.

> Our macOS containers contain multiple versions of Ruby. The default version is the system-installed Ruby. The containers also include the latest stable versions of Ruby at the time that the container is built. We determine the stable versions of Ruby using the Ruby-Lang.org downloads page. The version of Ruby that are installed in each image are listed in the software manifests of each container.
>   https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/testing-ios/#using-custom-ruby-versions

Since you are building in Xcode 10. The macOS container image [10.0.0: Xcode 10.0 (Build 10A255)](https://circle-macos-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/image-manifest/build-456/index.html), ruby versions 2.3.7, 2.4.4, 2.5.1 are available to chruby.